# Browser Verification - JavaScript [not broad]

Tags: javascript, python

I want to make a downloader for a website but upon accessing it gives a 503 code which redirects to a different page which verifies the website by setting a cookie to the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Please wait 5 seconds...</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  (function(){
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
    b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
    b(
        function()
        {
          var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
          console.log(a);

          setTimeout(
            function()
            {
                var t,r,a,f, GoAfgzB={"mRlhVrXc":+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))};
                console.log(t,r,a,f)
                t = document.createElement('div');
                t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
                t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
                t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
                a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
                f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
                ;GoAfgzB.mRlhVrXc-=+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!![]));
                GoAfgzB.mRlhVrXc-=+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]));
                a.value = parseInt(GoAfgzB.mRlhVrXc, 10) + t.length;
                //f.submit();
            }
        , 4000);
    }, false);
  })();
  //]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<div style="position: relative; height: 130px;">
<div style="max-width: 635px; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 1000; text-align: center;
                position: relative; margin-top: 150px; width: 100%">
<img id="imgLogo" alt="jadopado" style="display: inline-block;" src="data:image/gif; charset=binary;base64,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"><br />
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div style="text-align: center">
Please wait 5 seconds...<br />Make sure to enable cookies and javascript.<br />This site does not work with "Mini browsers" (e.g. UC mini, Opera mini...)
</div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; visibility: hidden">
<div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript><h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1></noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
    <div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> said.website.</h1>
    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs">Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <form id="challenge-form" action="/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="c1d1a1e6c4a1b169a8b67d4590f3b84c"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1442159694.707-KSgt/GKmWG"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 20px;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is the source code which it redirects to. I would like help in converting the javascript code to python.

Also anyone mind explaning how {"mRlhVrXc":+((!+[]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))}; becomes 25. O.O

So far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class Authenticate():
    def doAuthentication(self, requestSession):
        r = requestSession.get('http://localhost')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        print r.text
        jschlValue = soup.find('input', {'name': 'jschl_vc'})['value']
        passValue = soup.find('input', {'name': 'pass'})['value']

Auth = Authenticate()
Auth.doAuthentication(requests.session())
```

Comment: Python requests are text browser, do they interact with JS?

Comment: No it doesn't interact with the JS if it did I wouldn't have this issue ;_:

Comment: Can anybody help with my question?

Comment: It's JS.... It can't work in text browsers

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is the exactly same code Cloudflare uses to verify a browser when you enable the "I'm under attack" mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part of the question of how the obfuscated code leads to "25":

```
!+[]+!![]+[]
```

Is the same as:

```
!(+[]) + !(![])   + []
```

`+[]` (unary `+` on an array) converts the array to an integer, which gives `0`, and `+0` is `0`.

Meanwhile, `![]` converts the array to a boolean (which is true - any object is truthy in Javascript), and the negation of that is `false`.

```
!(0)   + !(false) + []
true   + true     + []
```

`true + true` converts the booleans to integers and adds them, giving you `2`.

```
2                 + []
```

This addition converts both arguments to strings, giving `"2" + ""` which is just:

```
"2"
```

---

The `5` is accomplished similarly:

```
!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]
!(+[]) + !![] + !![] + !![] + !![]
true   + true + true + true + true
5
```

And `"2" + 5` is `"25"`.

Comment: Thanks, do you understand the rest of the JavaScript code as well? If so mind explaining it :)

Comment: I figured how the rest of it was working, but couldn't of done it without this answer :D

Comment: Hi, could you explain how you figured out how to pass these tests please? :)